# Change value in DB of associated model through Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, rails-activerecord

I am using Devise for users, and I have another model called “Host Requests” that allows users to submit an application for different access levels on the site.  In the user model, I have a column (boolean) for the different types of access roles available.  I am trying to create an admin dashboard where all the host requests that have been submitted are listed for review.  I am trying to create two buttons next to the host request that allows the admin to “Approve” or “Decline” the user’s request.  If approved, it would change the User DB column to TRUE, if declined it would change it to FALSE.  I’ve added my additional attributes to the Devise Sanitizer for update, but for some reason I can’t get the table to update for the user_id attached to the host_request.  When the button is clicked, it ends up changing the value for the current_user.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!

**Model - user.rb**

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord

      has_many :host_requests
      has_many :timeslots
      has_many :experiences
      has_many :reservations
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

      validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}

      after_create :send_admin_mail


      def send_admin_mail
        UserMailer.send_welcome_email(self).deliver_later
      end

    end
```

**Model - host_requests.rb**

```
    class HostRequest < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
    end
```

**Controller - host_requests_controller.rb**

```
    class HostRequestsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_host_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      load_and_authorize_resource


      # GET /host_requests
      # GET /host_requests.json
      def index
        if current_user.admin_role?
          redirect_to admin_url
        else current_user.host_role?
          @host_requests = current_user.host_requests
        end
      end

      # GET /host_requests/1
      # GET /host_requests/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /host_requests/new
      def new
        @host_request = HostRequest.new
        @host_request.user = current_user
      end

      # GET /host_requests/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /host_requests
      # POST /host_requests.json
      def create
        @host_request = current_user.host_requests.new(host_request_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @host_request.save
            format.html { redirect_to @host_request, notice: 'Host request was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @host_request }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @host_request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /host_requests/1
      # PATCH/PUT /host_requests/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @host_request.update(host_request_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @host_request, notice: 'Host request was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @host_request }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @host_request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /host_requests/1
      # DELETE /host_requests/1.json
      def destroy
        @host_request.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to host_requests_url, notice: 'Host request was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_host_request
          @host_request = HostRequest.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def host_request_params
          params.require(:host_request).permit(:user_id, :why_host, :your_skills, :your_eco)
        end
    end
```

**Form - Admin Dashboard**

```
    <% @host_requests.each do |request| %>
      <div class="row mr-1 mt-1 ml-1">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p><strong>User Name: </strong><%= request.user.fullname %></p>
          <p><strong>Why Host: </strong><%= request.why_host %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
          <%= form_for(request.user, url: user_registration_path(request.user), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :host_role, value: true %>
            <%= f.submit "Approve", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right mr-1 ml-1"%>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

**Devise - registrations_controller.rb**

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
       before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]


      def update_resource(resource, params)
        resource.update_without_password(params)
      end

      # GET /resource/sign_up
      # def new
      #   super
      # end

      # POST /resource
      # def create
      #   super
      # end

      # GET /resource/edit
      # def edit
      #   super
      # end

      # PUT /resource
      # def update
      #   super
      # end

      # DELETE /resource
      # def destroy
      #   super
      # end

      # GET /resource/cancel
      # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
      # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
      # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
      # removing all OAuth session data.
      # def cancel
      #   super
      # end


      # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
       def configure_sign_up_params
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:host_role])
       end

      # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
       def configure_account_update_params
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:host_role])
       end


      # The path used after sign up.
      # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      #   super(resource)
      # end

      # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
      # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      #   super(resource)
      # end
    end
```

Comment: First, you need to do authorization. You can't update other users right now because I'm guessing you only have devise authentication. You can only update your own user record. Check this out: http://rubyjunky.com/authorization-and-authentication-in-a-Rails-api.html

Comment: I have Cancancan setup for user authorization.  When this is happening, I’m logged in as an admin_role user, and in the ability.rb I have the admin set to "can :manage, :all”.  So as far as authorization i should be good to go, as I can update user’s via the RailsAdmin which I have setup while building my own dashboards.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the controller look like that you're using here: user_registration_path(request.user).

Comment: I believe it is related to the Devise registrations controller, however there are no actions for update/edit/create/etc..  I was originally following a tutorial, and on the edit_registration view for Devise, this was the controller it referenced for the form.  I took that code, and used the same form setup for my host_requests admin panel.  I’ve add that controller to the question above!

Comment: I think that's the issue. The Devise registration controller authenticates_user before actions. I would suggest writing your own method to update the user, instead of using the stock devise registration path.

Comment: Would I add an update method in the user.rb?  Or should that method go into the registrations controller?

Comment: the person below wrote an answer that is exactly what I was suggesting. Writing your own methods that's outside the scope of the scaffolded methods is always a great solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this update outside of Devise

**routes.rb**

```
post ‘host-updater/:id’, to: ‘some_controller#some_action’, as: :host_update
```

**some_controller.rb**

```
def some_action
    user = User.find params[:id]
    user.update_attributes user_params
    redirect_to request.referrer, notice: ‘updated’
end

...

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit .....
end
```

**in your form_for**

```
form_form request.user, url: host_update_path, html: { method: :post } do |f|

     ......

end
```